# Zeros of Ramanujan tau L-function

Tags: nt.number-theory

Does anyone know if a formula for the  number of zeros of the L-series based on Ramanujan tau in the strip  0< Re(s) < 12 up to height T has been computed, i.e. the analog of Riemann's N(T)?    I wish to compare with a recent result.

Comment: Yes, this is just the argument principle.  I am a little  surprised by your question.  For your earlier question on Dirichlet L-functions I pointed to Davenport, and you found it worked out in Montgomery and Vaughan.  These are standard proofs, and analogs would apply to any $L$-function that you care to write down.

Comment: Thanks again Lucia.   But we didn't find the explicit formula we wanted to compare with in Davenport,  but did in Montgomery's book specifically for the Dirichlet L-functions.   Can you point me to a reference that has a general explicit result for all L-functions?    That is,  rather than a standard methodology,  i.e a standard contour integral we would have to do?   Sorry,I'm just not an expert on the literature, which is why I am on this site.

Comment: Try Analytic Number Theory by Iwaniec and Kowalski. I imagine it's in Chapter 5.

Comment: This just appeared on the arxiv: http://arxiv.org/abs/1310.0765

Comment: Peter,  thanks,  I did find a general result in Iwaniec and Kowlaski.   The only write the leading T log T term, but presumably it is a standard procedure to include the corrections.    This leading term did agree with our result obtained by very different methods.